# How to set title to UIPopOverController's Navigation Bar?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, avfoundation, uipopovercontroller

I am working on IPad application.Here it consists of PopOver.There I need to show camera and capture the image.For that I am using AVFoundation Framework,where default navigation bar is not appeared.So I followed the below procedure

```
cameraVC = [[CameraViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CameraViewController" bundle:nil ];
cameraVC.navigationItem.title = @"Take Photo";

UINavigationController *naviCon = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:cameraVC];

UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:naviCon];
 self.popoverController = popover;
 self.popoverController.delegate = self;
 self.popover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(450, 350);

[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(295, 40, 0, 0) inView:appDelegate.splitview.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Please guide me where I was wrong if you  have worked on it.Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: With the code you've shown, I can't reproduce the issue at all, so I'd suspect the problem is somewhere else. It does seem a bit odd though that you seem to have both a `popover` and a `popoverController` property. You're setting the `popoverContentSize` of `self.popover`, but where does that come from? You don't initialize that anywhere in your code (at least not in the part you've shown).

Answer (score -1):

Modify code as below and check

```
cameraVC = [[CameraViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *naviCon = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:cameraVC];

UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:naviCon];
 [self.presentPopOverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:self.yourBarButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

and then in `viewDidLoad` method of `CameraViewController` write following code

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"your title";
```

Answer (score -1):

If the Navigation bar does not appear, add a UIToolBar in your cameraViewController to do the functionality you want.

I do something like this in my project and I get the navigationBar in the popOVer presented.

```
        PageSelectorViewController *pageSelector=[[PageSelectorViewController  alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain] ;
        UINavigationController *navControl=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:pageSelector];

        self.selectedPagesPopOver=[[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:navControl];
        [self.selectedPagesPopOver presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:showPages permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

I guess presenting the popOver from a custom rect is the problem, try to present from a BarButton and try.

Comment: What apple standards are you talking about @HariniGoutham, I dont see anything wrong in my code.

Answer (score -1):

This could help you…

```
MyController* controller = [[MyController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController* navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];

controller.title = @"My Title"; //or you can put this line in MyController class viewDidLoad method as self.title = @"My Title";

controller.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 480.0);

_myPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController];

[_myPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```